# Excel: Is it possible to partially sort this way?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

Suppose in column B of a sheet i have the following data row-wise:

```
New York zip- 2067 . Temperature cool  
Beijing  zip- 1063 . Temperature is chilly  
Africa   zip- 3069 . Temperature is hot
```

so on

I want to sort the column by order of zip values.
So in this case it will be:

```
Beijing zip- 1063 . Temperature is hot  
New York .......
```

and so on upto nth row....

How to do this. Is there any way/formula?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Thanks for editing

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't follow your question because you are moving around data from one row to another.  Maybe you can explain why you need to do this.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen To sort zip values. I just need it in ascending order and the rest will be placed in the rows accordingly

Comment: Yes there is a way.  Extract the values you wish to sort on to a "helper column" using string functions, then sort on that column.  Edit your original question with what you have tried, and where you have run  into problems.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld if i would use the helper column then i cannot insert them accordingly in the original column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is on A column then paste this on B column: **=ABS(VALUE(MID(A1;SEARCH("zip-";A1;1)+3;7)))** this extract just the zip code.

follow this 5 steps:

### [01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33fH9.png)

### [02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bavbz.png)

### [03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdSJd.png)

### [04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cvagq.png)

### [05](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIThO.png)

Comment: but will the original column strings will also be arranged according to the sorted zip codes?

Comment: yes, but to make it automatic, I will edit my answer

Comment: CN Viana The formula u gave it's showing an error. Please help

Comment: CN viana the formula showing an error, help pls

Comment: CN Viana In place of ; it will be comma, i got it btw thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you can & will code in VBA, you can do the following:

- Read the every cell of the range and take the part between `.` and the `zip-`.
- Then put this part at the beginning of the range.
- Sort the range, which would be sorted by the number
- Remove the numeric part

If you put the values in `A1:A3` it would be like this:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim readDataArr     As Variant
    Dim testArr         As Variant
    Dim cnt             As Long
    Dim myCell          As Range
    Dim addSomething    As String
    Dim separator       As String

    separator = "SomethingQuiteUniqe"

    For Each myCell In Range("A1:A3")
        'Read the every cell of the range and take the part between . and the zip-.
        addSomething = Split(Split(myCell, "zip-")(1), ".")(0)
        'Then put this part at the beginning of the range.
        myCell = addSomething & separator & myCell
    Next myCell

        'Sort the range, which would be sorted by the number
    Range("A1:A3").Sort key1:=Range("A1:A3")

        'Remove the numeric part
    For Each myCell In Range("A1:A3")
        myCell = Split(myCell, separator)(1)
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

These are the steps:

1. Input:

[image]

2. After putting the separator to the string and sorting it:

[image]

3. Removing the first part after the sort:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering

Comment: @pandong - welcome.